# Can I use a RN2483 to make a LoraWAN gateway?

Tags: communication, microchip, lora

I have a Microchip [RN2483](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/RN2483) LoRaWAN module and I would like to use it for making a LoraWAN Gateway. Is it possible? If it is, how can I do it? Or if it is not, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to create a "full" LoRaWAN gateway using the RN2483 because RN2483 can only listen on one channel. A full gateway needs to listen on multiple channels because LoRaWAN devices randomly select which channel to send on.

However, it is possible to create a single channel gateway. Such gateway would not be LoRaWAN-compatible, but can still solve some use cases. More information: https://www.thethingsnetwork.org/forum/t/single-channel-gateway-with-rn2483/1848

Comment: Mikael Falkvidd, how do you know that RN2483 can only listen one channel? How can I be sure about another microchips? If I can find it in the datasheet, please tell me where. I have to create a full LoRaWAN Gateway.